# What happens to apps/containers in YARN when node is temporarily disconnected from network

Tags: hadoop, networking, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

This question is more to understand the behaviour of the container thats run in YARN, when its disconnected from network for a brief period of time. Any pointers will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The application manager of the job will re-attempt the job